# register_activation_hook vs add_action('init')

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to determine why some WordPress plugins use `register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate_plugin')` while others use the action `add_action('init', 'activate_plugin');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few reasons:

- register_activation_hook is WP2+, add_action was available to use before that
- register_activation_hook allows the developer to specify the file the function resides in (although this seems rarely used)
- for me, register_activation_hook is 'cleaner'

So I'd bet that plugins using add_action date from before version 2 or the developer isn't aware of register_activation_hook

Comment: Thanks Adam. I really appreciate that here at SO you can almost always get a concise, clear explanation of things. And quickly :)

Comment: According to @nacin (a lead developer for WordPress), you shouldn’t use activation hooks (especially on multisite). You should do this instead:

“It’s far better to use an upgrade routine fired on admin_init, and handle that per-site, basing it on a stored option.”

Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14170#comment:68

Comment: Interesting, thanks @Sam. That discussion is specifically about network (ie multisite) installations, which I don't think were a 'thing' back when I wrote this (we had WPMU instead) - I'll have a further read and see if I can update my answer.

Answer (score 17):

The two do different things, `register_activation_hook` is used to register a function which will be called once when the plug-in is activated (on the Wordpress plug-in management page), whereas functions hooked into the `init` action will be called on every request.

So, common examples would be to use an activation function to create database tables, or set default options for a plug-in and then an `init` action function to load translated strings.

Answer (score 1):

Hooking an "activate_plugin" function to init looks to either be code done a long time ago, or by someone who doesn't know about register_activation_hook.  A third possibility is that despite the function name they want it to run whether or not register_activation_hook is called.

For example, when *updating* a plugin, the plugin is deactivated and reactivated, but the activate hook is not called.  (And it's certainly not called if the plugin is updated via FTP or similar.)  So if I were putting in some code that need to run on activate **or after an update** I might hook it to init.