# Difference about add_action('init', ...) and add_action('admin_menu', ...)

Tags: php, wordpress

i have programmed an plugin for wordpress where i load the menu. There are 2 types how i can load the menu and both are working. 
is the difference that init is loading before admin_menu or admin_menu before init ? It is just a thing about load-time? Or When i should use which of them? I guess admin_menu is just for loading the menu and init can do more and admin_menu i can use just for this menu to add but i am realy confused when and why to use which of them.
My code is here:

```
add_action('admin_menu','admin_menu_option');
function admin_menu_option(){add_menu_page('My Script','My-Site','manage_options','admin-menu','my_page','',200);}
```

or

```
add_action('init','admin_menu_option');
function admin_menu_option(){add_menu_page('My Script','My-Site','manage_options','admin-menu','my_page','',200);}
```

Here on the site: 
There are other Threads with similiar Question but that dont help me:

[WordPress Plugin Customize menu and submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941896/wordpress-plugin-customize-menu-and-submenu) [What is add_action( 'init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201266/what-is-add-action-init) [register_activation_hook vs add_action('init')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417524/register-activation-hook-vs-add-actioninit)

[How to fix add_action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544418/how-to-fix-add-action)

The information from the official source is here: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init but that dont helps me too.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu 
they write that admin_init is called after admin_menu but what is about 'init'?

Answer (score 0):

init is for more general plugin initialisation, and executes for each page view both on the frontend of the site and in wp-admin.

admin_menu only gets triggered when the admin panel menu is actually going to be shown so it's slightly more efficient to use this for adding menu items.

It's also executed after init so if you had some dependencies which needed their init functions to be executed first, you'd be sure that was all completed by the time admin_menu got triggered.